# FirebaseAuth and FirebaseDatabase not saving Google sign ups

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a system that saves createUserWithEmailAndPassword data to a realtime database and to the authentication database. But after making a similar system using google sign in instead nothing will save to the database and neither does anything save to the Authentication database.

ive tried using Log.e, ive tried debugging the app and also tried to decode the code...

heres some code:

```
package com.brandshopping.brandshopping;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class LoginOrSignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button LoginBtn, RegisterWithEmailBtn, RegisterWithGoogleBtn;
    private String Tag;
    private ProgressDialog LoadingBar;

    private FirebaseDatabase firebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference database = firebasedatabase.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_or_signup);

        LoadinGUI();



        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso); //Create Google sign in object


        LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, LogInActivity.class));
            }
        });

        RegisterWithEmailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

        RegisterWithGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.Register_WithGoogle_btn:
                        signIn();
                        break;
                }

           }
        });
    }

    private void signIn() {

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, gso); //Create Google sign in object

        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

        int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Register/signin successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, AccountInfoActivity.class));




        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Log in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(Tag, "error: ");
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, AccountInfoActivity.class));

        }
    }

    void SaveToDataBase(){

        database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                GoogleSignInAccount Guser = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(LoginOrSignupActivity.this);
                String EmailWithEtheraRemoved = Guser.getEmail().replace(".", " ");

                if(!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(EmailWithEtheraRemoved).exists())){
                    LoadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we load the credentialls in");
                    LoadingBar.setTitle("Register");
                    LoadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    LoadingBar.show();

                    HashMap<String, Object> Userdatamap = new HashMap<>();

                    Userdatamap
                            .put("Email", Guser.getEmail());

                    Userdatamap
                            .put("Phone number", "Google intigrated sign in does not allow phone number requesting... This will be fixed in later patches");

                    Userdatamap
                            .put("Name", Guser.getGivenName() + Guser.getFamilyName());

                    if(Guser != null){
                        Userdatamap
                                .put("Created with", "Intigrated Google sign in");
                    }

                    database
                            .child("Users")
                            .child(EmailWithEtheraRemoved)
                            .updateChildren(Userdatamap)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    LoadingBar.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, "Database save successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("SignUpError :", task
                                            .getException()
                                            .getMessage());


                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e(Tag, "error: ");
                        }
                    });

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    void LoadinGUI(){

        LoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R. id. Login_btn);
        RegisterWithEmailBtn = (Button) findViewById(R. id. Register_WithEmail_btn);
        RegisterWithGoogleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R. id. Register_WithGoogle_btn);

    }

}
```

I am expecting the app to save info to the realtime database as well as the authentication database. Niether of that seems to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the `SaveToDataBase` after sign in Successfully. That's why there's no log and database entry.

Comment: Omg i am stuuupid

Comment: it is, But nothing is saving to the Authentication database

Comment: have you tried with logging you're data cause i have doubt you're code not providing you enough data.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling firebase signin after you have received the result from Google Signin.

Inside your `handleSignInResult` you have result from google signin, you just need to create GoogleAuth credentials and use it to `signInwithCredentials`.

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        saveUpdateUserProfile(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
```

This will create/login the firebase user and then you can check db to see if the google account used to sign in is new account to save info of user.

P.S you can optimize the query of your db as well. your current query will get all the users from db. Also you should not use the email address as key in database.

More efficient db structure can be with using firebase user id as key:

```
users: {
 firebaaseUID1: {},
 firebaaseUID2: {},
 .
 .
}
```

Your `SaveToDataBase` can now be:

void SaveToDataBase(FirebaseUser user, boolean isGoogleSignIn) {

```
database.getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid())
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    // firebase user data is present in db, do appropiate action or take user to home screen
                }
                else {
                    LoadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we load the credentialls in");
                    LoadingBar.setTitle("Register");
                    LoadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    LoadingBar.show();
                    HashMap<String, Object> Userdatamap = new HashMap<>();

                    Userdatamap.put("Email", user.getEmail());

                    // Userdatamap
                    //         .put("phoneNumber", "Google intigrated sign in does not allow phone number requesting... This will be fixed in later patches");

                    Userdatamap.put("Name", user.getDisplayName());

                    if (isGoogleSignIn)
                        Userdatamap.put("Created with", "Intigrated Google sign in");

                    database
                            .child("Users")
                            .child(user.getUid())
                            .updateChildren(Userdatamap)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    LoadingBar.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, "Database save successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("SignUpError :", task
                                            .getException()
                                            .getMessage());
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginOrSignupActivity.this, "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e(Tag, "error: ");
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am considering that you have already added firebase to your project if not then follow this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Then you have to enable google signIn in the Firebase by selecting Authentication from left panel then select sign in provider tab and enable google sign IN.

your project level buildscript should look like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And app level build.gradle file should have these dependencies

```
//firebasecore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
//firebase auth
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
//google auth
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

and login should have code like this

```
public class Login_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


ImageView gLogin;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN=1;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
Firebase user;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

 user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user!=null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login_Activity.this,MainActivity.class));
        Login_Activity.this.finish();

    }

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_);

    gLogin=findViewById(R.id.gLogin);

    // ...
// Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
 GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient= GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);



    gLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });


}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
 Toast.makeText(this, "starting activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from 
GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
// The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to 
   //attach
        // a listener.
 Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = 
 GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
    Toast.makeText(this, "inside on Activity result", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
   Toast.makeText(this, "authenticating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w("firebase exception", "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
        //handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d("authenticate", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = 
GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() 
{
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) 
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
  // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

  Log.d("message","signInWithCredential:success");
                        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Log.d("user id", user.getUid());
                        startActivity(new 
Intent(Login_Activity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        Login_Activity.this.finish();

                    } else {
              // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("message","signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

you need to requestId token with google sign In options you can use this code it will log you with google login with entries in firebase authenticated user database.

For Database you should once check  databse rules for read write permission and it should work